# Winform command line argument returning executable filename

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters

I am trying to pass a command line argument to a winform I have but no matter what I specify as the parameter it keeps returning the winform filename and path.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
}
```

The messagebox will show `C:\App\MyApp.exe` even if at a cmd I type `C:\App\MyApp.exe param1` which should output `param1`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, school boy error! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.

The first argument on the command line is always the executable name.

To get the first argument passed to the executable, get the next parameter (assuming one exists):

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

The first entry (index 0) is always the path of the executable. You need to access index 1. Try this instead:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    if (arguments.Length > 1) {
        MessageBox.Show(arguments[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first command-line argument is always the path to the program.
`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]` will be `"param1"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]
```

returns the path to your executable.

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]
... 
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[n]
```

will return `n` consecutive parameters.

The `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` returns an array of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument will be always the name of the executable. parameters start from 1.
so Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1] will give the 1st argument.

Answer (score 0):

Or, my favorite...

```
foreach (var arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1))
{
    // process each arg in turn.
}
```